# Abstracting mutable/immutable references in rust

Tags: rust, reference, mutable

I need to get rid of duplication in this code:

```rust
pub struct Memory {
    layout: MemoryLayout,
    rom: Vec<u8>,
    ram: Vec<u8>,
}

impl Memory {
    pub fn get_mem_vec_ref(&self, address: u32) -> Result<&Vec<u8>, RiscvError> {
        // ...

        let mem_vec_ref = match address {
            addr if (rom_start..rom_end).contains(&addr) => Ok(&self.rom),
            addr if (ram_start..ram_end).contains(&addr) => Ok(&self.ram),
            addr => Err(RiscvError::MemoryAlignmentError(addr)),
        }?;

        return Ok(mem_vec_ref);
    }

    pub fn get_mem_vec_mut_ref(&mut self, address: u32) -> Result<&mut Vec<u8>, RiscvError> {
        // ...

        let mem_vec_ref = match address {
            addr if (rom_start..rom_end).contains(&addr) => Ok(&mut self.rom),
            addr if (ram_start..ram_end).contains(&addr) => Ok(&mut self.ram),
            addr => Err(RiscvError::MemoryAlignmentError(addr)),
        }?;

        return Ok(mem_vec_ref);
    }
}
```

How can I abstract using mutable vs immutable reference to self? Can `Box` or `RefCell` be helpful in this case?

Comment: Does `get_mem_vec_mut_ref` modify `self`?

Comment: No, it only returns a mutable reference to struct's inner vector. `&self` would not work inside `get_mem_vec_mut_ref` because then I can't borrow `&mut self.rom` mutably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're dealing with references in both cases, then you can define a generic function, where `T` would be either `&Vec<u8>` or `&mut Vec<u8>`. So you can do something like this:

```rust
fn get_mem<T>(address: u32, rom: T, ram: T) -> Result<T, RiscvError> {
    // ...

    match address {
        addr if (rom_start..rom_end).contains(&addr) => Ok(rom),
        addr if (ram_start..ram_end).contains(&addr) => Ok(ram),
        addr => Err(RiscvError::MemoryAlignmentError(addr)),
    }
}

impl Memory {
    pub fn get_mem_vec_ref(&self, address: u32) -> Result<&Vec<u8>, RiscvError> {
        // ...

        let mem_vec_ref = get_mem(address, &self.rom, &self.ram)?;

        return Ok(mem_vec_ref);
    }

    pub fn get_mem_vec_mut_ref(&mut self, address: u32) -> Result<&mut Vec<u8>, RiscvError> {
        // ...

        let mem_vec_ref = get_mem(address, &mut self.rom, &mut self.ram)?;

        return Ok(mem_vec_ref);
    }
}
```

Now, obviously you need to modify `get_mem()` to account for `rom_start`, `rom_end`, `ram_start`, `ram_end`. If you want to avoid having to pass 100 fields to `get_mem()`, then it might be worth introducing a newtype to deal with addresses instead, e.g. something like:

```rust
struct Addr {
    // ...
}

impl Addr {
    fn get_mem<T>(&self, rom: T, ram: T) -> Result<T, RiscvError> {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This way when I add another type of memory I would need to add arguments to `get_mem` function. I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: @TonyI. I'd need more context, to provide a better suggestion. When you say another type of memory, are you referring to another `Vec<u8>` in `Memory` or a completely separate type? Additionally, I'm assuming that `*_start` and `_end` are assocated with the `Vec<u8>` of the same name. So maybe they should be together in 1 type. Again, I can speculate about a lot of the things, but will need more context to give better ideas. So for now, if you purely want to eliminate the duplicate code that you provided, then this is how you can do so

Comment: By additional memory types I mean something like memory-mapped IO address space added in `Memory` struct. Your solution works well really, now that I think about adding 1-2 arguments would not be a big overhead later on. I will use it so it is +1 and accept from me.